# how to handle this circular dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I have a MyApp solution. This solution has a Services project and a Repositories (DAL) project. The application pattern is that each service calls a corresponding repository for data access.

The Services project has a LoggingService and I want to log some information from one of the repositories using the LoggingService. However, I can't add a reference to the Services project in the Repositories project b/c this would cause a circular dependency.

A workaround would be for me to simply call the LoggingRepository directly instead of calling the service.  Is there a better way to handle this circular dependency?

Comment: Could you post some stubbed code to help clarify your situation? I would think it's possible to invert the dependencies so each repository has a service it uses when needed but I can't tell if that will work without some example code

Answer (score 0):

Of course their are many way to deal with this situation, first of all I would create an interface for each service and put it in separate dll for example you would have two projects for the logging service as following:

- ILoggingService
- LoggingService
  and I would also do this for every single boundedContext, which represent a group of projects that deal with single aspect inside my domain (for example the students operations and logic inside school application, search for Domain driven design pattern for more information) as following:
- IStudentsDomain
- StudentsDomain

And lets imagine that we have other repositories and bounded context called Teachers represented in the following projects as following:

- ITeachersDomain
- TeachersDomain

Now you only refers to ILoggingService inside StudentsDomain and TeachersDomain (the DAL implementation or the domain layer), and use Dependency injection (based on your project for asp.net mvc I would recommend Unity,inside asp.net core mvc the DI is already exists out of box, and finally you can use unity in WPF too) in order to register your interfaces with their implementation and then request them inside the constructor of StudentsDomain and TeachersDomain as following:

```
public class TeachersDomain : ITeachersDomain
{
    public ILoggingService LoggingService { get; set; }
    public TeachersDomain(ILoggingService loggingService)
    {
        LoggingService = loggingService;
    }
}
```